# Create matrix in R whose elements are associated to a pair of numbers

Tags: r, matrix

I am quite new to coding R..so I really appreciate your patience and time (thank you!).

I need to create a matrix in R like the one I attach: each element of this matrix 5x9 is the maximum between the number of row and the sum of the two numbers in parenthesis (that are clearly combinations of the number 0,1,2 in groups of two). 
I already know how to construct matrix in R.In this case the problem relates to the fact that each element of the matrix depends on an associated pair of numbers. 
I am aware that this request can sounds strange, but any kind of help would be really appreciated. 
Thank you!

```
|   |(0,0)|(1,0)|(2,0)|(0,1)|(1,1)|(2,1)|(0,2)|(1,2)|(2,2)|
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1 |  1     1     2     1     2     3     2     3     4  
| 2 |  2     2     2     2     2     3     2     3     4
| 3 |  3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     4
| 4 |  4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
| 5 |  5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
```

Comment: Make both matrices and use `pmax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
vals <- rowSums(expand.grid(0:2, 0:2))
x <- rep(1:5, 9)
m <- matrix(pmax(x, vals[rep(1:9, each = 5)]), nrow = 5)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    1    1    2    1    2    3    2    3    4
# [2,]    2    2    2    2    2    3    2    3    4
# [3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    4
# [4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4
# [5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works fine...I wouldn't think that it was possible. thank you again

Comment: Sorry mt1022...what if the operation to determine the value of the element of the matrix involve only, let's say, the first number of the pair. Denoting the pair as (a,b), what if each element of the matrix is the maximum between the number of the row and a?

Comment: @Andrea, if I unstandard it correctly, you just need to set `vals` to `rep(0:2, 3)`.

Comment: It works!After a while I've understood the logic of the code.You've been very helpful and I hope to have no more questions. Thank you!!